# Use picture as submit button

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, haml

I would like to make my submit button for my login page be a picture instead of the grey button. When I use css to do this I get the button on top of the picture. Is there a way to use

```
= submit_tag image_tag('image/location.jpg) 'Login', :id => 'Login'
```

If I could resize the button to a certain dimension that would work as well since I can place it where I want with css.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is an `<input type="image" src="..."/>` that will make an image act as a submit button. I don't know ruby on rails, but a quick search turned up `image_submit_tag(source, options = {})`. You can look at the docs [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-image_submit_tag).

Comment: This works great, however is there a way I can change the dimensions of this? It still makes a "button sized" button with a background of the image I want to use.

Comment: @Blackdragon1400 - Add `width="x" height="x"` attributes to the tag so it matches your image size. I think you can do that like this `image_submit_tag(source, :size => "{width}x{height}")`.

Comment: Your above code should work, but the image is still not getting re-sized... It runs on the rails server so it's syntactically correct and I checked it out, so I'm not sure what the problem is exactly.

Comment: I really don't know rails, the only thing I can think of is some css that is overriding the width and height you provided. Try adding an id to the tag and add the size in the css explicitly.

Comment: Yeah I've actually tried both both ways, with only css and a background image it puts it where it needs to go and is the correct size, however I cant make it a button for it t work with rails. With just haml code it makes the button and image but the wrong size =(

Comment: Do you have a link to the result you get so far?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
.element {
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-image: url(path/img-png) no-repeat 0 0;
    background-size: /* (desired size in pixels or %) */ 40px 50px;
    -moz-background-size: /* (desired size in pixels or %) */ 40px 50px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    /* any other desired rules */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the `<input>` button with an `<img>` tag is not a good idea because it violates the principle of [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement): you should keep your website as accessible as possible, while enhansing its capabilites when the browser allows it.

In your case, there's a pure CSS solution to turn the classic `<input type=submit>` button into an image:

```
input {

  /* sizing the button */
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;

  /* disabling the system look */
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;

  /* resetting default browser styler */
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  /* hiding button label */
  text-indent: -9999px;

  /* applying the image */
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/1x8TMLt.jpg') no-repeat transparent;
  background-size: 100% 100%; /* stretching */

  /* letting users know it's clickable */
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

When CSS is unavailable for some reason, the button will appear as a button with a text label. When the CSS is available, the button will appear as an image of given size, yay!

Demo: http://jsbin.com/okasut/1/edit

Of course, you should use some semantic selector.

Answer (score 0):

submit_tag generates an html `input type='submit'`. You want an html `button`, which rails can generate using [button_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-button_tag).

```
= button_tag :id => 'Login' do
  image_tag('image/location.jpg')
```